# override variables of upper classes

Tags: inheritance, dart, overriding, flutter

I have an upper class that has a `var title` and then I have different classes, that extend this upper one, in which I want to override that `var title`.

I was trying with `@override void set` method, but I didn't understand how to use it properly. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use getter and setter combined with `super` to achieve the desired result:

```
class Foo {
  String title;
}

class Override extends Foo {
  String get title {
    print("get title");
    return super.title;
  }

  set title(value) {
    print("Set title");
    super.title = value;
  }
}
```

---

```
Foo f = Override();
f.title = "Hello World";
print(f.title);
```

This will print

```
Set title
get title
Hello World
```

Comment: Actually, I want that this had to be done automatically, without instanciating the class and then setting the title. So, when I instanciate the sublcass object, it must already have the new title

Comment: That's just a constructor. Nothing prevents you from adding a constructor to `Override` that sets a default title

Comment: Understood, I was getting a little bit confused by what I had to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-initialize in a subclass the not private variables of an extended or implemented upper class **before compiling**, then look at this example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778696/13766744