# how can i initialize super class variables in dart language?

Tags: dart

Simply i have to classes child and parent class 
 i am new in dart language all i need to assign super class properties from child class

this is super class structure

```
class Trip{
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final double price;
  Trip({this.id,this.title,this.price});
}
```

and this is child class

```
class FullTrip extends Trip{
  final String data;
  FullTrip({this.data}) : super(id:id,title:title,price:price);
}
```

sure this not working at all
 
the question is : how can i initialize instance from FullTrip and pass variable for FullTrip and Trip(super class)
thanks in advance

Comment: This is how it's done. What part is not working and what exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: how can i initialize instance from FullTrip and pass variable for FullTrip and Trip(super class) from constructor

Comment: I missed that you didn't have the parameters in `FullTrip`. See my answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that means "das Auto ist kaputt" :P

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to repeat the parameters in the subclass.

```
class FullTrip extends Trip{
  final String data;
  FullTrip({this.data, int id, String title, double price}) : super(id:id,title:title,price:price);
}
```

There are discussions about reducing such boilerplate for constructors, but nothing is decided yet as far as I know.

Comment: class FullTrip extends Trip{
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final double price;
  final String data;
  
  FullTrip({this.data,this.id,this.title,this.price}) : super(id,title,price);

}

???

Comment: Why would you repeat the fields in `fullTrip`? They are already in `Trip` and inherited by `FullTrip`. This way you create the storage location twice which is prone to lead to weird bugs.

Comment: i am asking for that and you told me in your answer above first line "You need to repeat the parameters in the subclass." !? so what you mean i need to use super class vars in child class instead of
 from repeat it

Comment: You need to repeat the constructor parameters, not the field declaration - as shown in my answer.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer  this issue is very annoying especially if you want to subclass a Flutter Widget. Is there a document or anything you can point to about these discussions to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, How to achieve this for factory constructors in null safety mode?

Comment: Note that there is now a cleaner way to do this. See the answer from @CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 10):

User `super-parameters`, which were added in Dart `2.17`. For example, say this is your class:

```dart
class Parent {
  Parent({
    int? i,
    bool b = false,
    required String s,
  });
}
```

#### Old way (boilerplate code)

Earlier you had to do something like this:

```dart
class Child extends Parent {
  Child({
    int? i,
    bool b = false,
    required String s,
  }) : super(
          i: i,
          b: b,
          s: s,
        );
}
```

#### New way (neat and clean)

But now you can get rid of those boilerplate code.

```dart
class Child extends Parent {
  Child({
    super.i, 
    super.b = false,
    required super.s,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-initialize in a subclass the not private variables of an extended or implemented upper class **before compiling**, simply use `@override`. Look at this example

*(if you want to try the code, have in mind it supports null safety. If your test doesn't, simply delete the `?` signs.)*

```
class Go {
  String? name = "No name";
}

class Foo implements Go { //use either implements or extends
  @override
  String? name = "Foo";
}

class Doo extends Go { //use either implements or extends
  @override
  String? name = "Doo";
}
```

**Use case example:** In the code above, you can see that in our upper class we have this `String name` variable. Then in the subclasses we can simply override that variable. After that, in main we can now for example do something like iterating through a `List<Go>`, access what we wanted to and then trigger something, like printing the name:

```
void main() {
  
  List<Go> foos = [
    Go(),
    Foo(),
    Doo(),
  ];
  
  for(Go x in foos){
    print(x.name);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
No name
Foo
Doo
```

This works if you use either the `extends` or `implements` keywords.