# How to override class variables in subclasses?

Tags: dart

I'm fairly new to Dart and am having trouble with some class inheritance. I want to know how to properly override class variables in subclasses.

This is a general language question. I'm coming from a mostly Python background and I think I'm just missing some central Dart concept.

So here is the general situation I'm looking for:

I have a base class `Foo` that defines some class variables and methods. The variable names are common to all subclasses of `Foo`, and the methods are common behaviour.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is:

In `foo.dart`:

```dart
class Foo {
  int _x;

  int timesTwo() {
    return _x * 2;
  }
}
```

Then in `bar.dart`:

```dart
import 'foo.dart';

class Bar extends Foo {
  int _x = 2;
}
```

And then in `main.dart`:

```dart
import 'bar.dart';

main() {
  Bar b = Bar();
  print(b.timesTwo()); // NoSuchMethodError: The method '*' was called on null.
}
```

I have tried various combinations of `static`, `final`, `_`, etc. It does work if I leave all the variables public, but that's not really ideal.

I understand that the `_x` variable is private, and access to it is limited to the file. And so `timesTwo()` is using the `_x` defined (or actually undefined) in `Foo`.

But I'm confused how to inherit the `timesTwo()` method from `Foo` and have it use the private variable in `Bar`.

Ideally, I would be able to define a collection of shared methods in the base class, then override the values in the subclasses.

Can someone help me understand how to define these class relationships so that I can use private, class variables with base class methods?

Edit: The question in [override variables of upper classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151651/override-variables-of-upper-classes) appears to be the same, but the answer shows using the super class variables in the subclass methods, whereas what I want is to define the behaviour in the super class, and override the variables in with those from the subclass.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [override variables of upper classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151651/override-variables-of-upper-classes)

Comment: I think it is the same idea, but the solution provided does not fit the solution I'm looking for. That solution is using the instance variables from the super class in the subclass. I am looking for a way to override the super class variables with those of the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override `_x` value in `Bar` class because `Foo` and `Bar` are in different libraries.

Just move `Bar` definition to `foo.dart` and `Bar` will be able to override `_x` because now they are both in the same libarary.

It's allowed to declare multiple classes in a single file in dart.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#consider-declaring-multiple-classes-in-the-same-library

> Placing multiple classes together in one library can enable some useful patterns. Since privacy in Dart works at the library level, not the class level, this is a way to define “friend” classes like you might in C++. Every class declared in the same library can access each other’s private members, but code outside of that library cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding private variables from outside the same library is not possible, as posted in the previous answer. This is the correct Dart way to handle private variables and libraries.

If this does not suit your use-case, like me, you can consider using public variables and a mixin solution. For me it looked like this:

In `foo.dart` change `_x` to just `x`:

```dart
class Foo {
  int x;

  int timesTwo() {
    return x * 2;
  }
}
```

And change both `_x` to `x`, and `extends` to `with` in `bar.dart`:

```dart
import 'foo.dart';

class Bar with Foo {
  int x = 2;
}
```

This will allow overriding of instance variables in inherited/mixin methods. But you do lose the "private" factor.

**Note:** the `with` keyword is not necessary, but in my case it makes the intention more explicit than the `extends` keyword. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-initialize in a subclass the not private variables of an extended or implemented upper class **before compiling**, look at this example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778696/13766744